# Javafx maven deployment under Intellij Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx, pom.xml

I have a maven based project under Intellij idea Editor. I'm using javafx-maven-plugin.
My goal is to deploy my project as EXE or MSI installable file.
Since this the first time using maven, plz help me to make a correct configuration for pom.xml file. Or is there another way easy than maven that can help me acheive my Goal, So, don't hesitate to mention it.

So, this my pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.abdo.EntrepriseLimted</groupId>
    <artifactId>EntrepriseLimited</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ENTREPRISELIMITED</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>MainApplication</mainClass>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <vendor>Abdo</vendor>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- required before build-native -->
            <id>create-jfxjar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>create-native</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-native</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>


        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/fxml</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.40.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfxtras-labs</artifactId>
            <version>8.0-r4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfxtras-controls</artifactId>
            <version>8.0-r4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

After executing this pom.xml using com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:jfx-jar.
I get this result showing this result :

```
Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ EntrepriseLimited ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\Projects\6.Project SI limted\2 nd iteration\2. Object Oriented design\target\EntrepriseLimited-1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< javafx-maven-plugin:8.2.0:jar (default-cli) @ EntrepriseLimited <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:8.2.0:jar (default-cli) @ EntrepriseLimited ---
[INFO] Building JavaFX JAR for application
[INFO] Adding 'deploy' directory to Mojo classpath: D:\Projects\6.Project SI limted\2 nd iteration\2. Object Oriented design/src/main/deploy
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.316s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 01 13:04:24 WAT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems that the project was successfully deployed but:
under target directory 
i get a file name "EntrepriseLimited-1.0.jar", after double click the file not works.
under target/jfx/ i get EntrepriseLimited-1.0-jfx.jar
under target/jfx/lib i see the dependencies. after double clicking the file "ntrepriseLimited-1.0-jfx.jar" it not works as well.

Here is main Application code :

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        buildMainWindow();

    }

    private void buildMainWindow() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent parent = new AnchorPane();
        System.out.println(getClass().getResource(""));
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("fxml/mainWindow.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(parent);
        try {

            parent = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Scene sc = new Scene(parent);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);

        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage stage) {
        this.primaryStage = stage;

    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And her is the controller for mainWindow where i open new windows, based on user 
Action:

```
public class MainWindowController implements Initializable {

    // Tabbed pane
    @FXML
    private TabPane tbTabPaneHome;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

     private void createTab(String title, AnchorPane parent) {
        Tab tab = new Tab(title);
        for (Tab child : tbTabPaneHome.getTabs()) {
            if (child.getText().equals(title)) {
                tbTabPaneHome.getSelectionModel().select(child);
                return;
            }
        }
        tab.setContent(parent);
        tbTabPaneHome.getTabs().addAll(tab);
        tbTabPaneHome.getSelectionModel().select(tab);
    }

    private Parent loadContent(URL resources) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Parent parent = new AnchorPane();
            loader.setLocation(resources);
            parent = loader.load();
            return parent;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private AnchorPane buildEntrepriseTab() {
        AnchorPane parent = (AnchorPane) loadContent(getClass()
                .getResource("../fxml/entreprise/entreprise.fxml"));
        return parent;
    }

    private AnchorPane buildTransactionTab() {
        AnchorPane parent = (AnchorPane) loadContent(getClass()
                .getResource("../fxml/transaction/transaction.fxml"));
        return parent;
    }

    private AnchorPane buildAccountTab() {
        AnchorPane parent = (AnchorPane) loadContent(getClass()
                .getResource("../fxml/account/account.fxml"));
        return parent;
    }

    private AnchorPane buildTypeOfTransactionTab() {
        AnchorPane parent = (AnchorPane) loadContent(getClass()
                .getResource("../fxml/TypeOfTransaction.fxml"));
        return parent;
    }


    private AnchorPane buildUserTab() {
        AnchorPane parent = (AnchorPane) loadContent(getClass()
                .getResource("../fxml/user/user.fxml"));
        return parent;
    }

    // Event Handling
    // Action events
    @FXML
    public void listDesEntrepriseClicked() {
        createTab("Entreprise", buildEntrepriseTab());
    }

    @FXML
    public void listTransactionClicked() {
        createTab("Transaction", buildTransactionTab());
    }

    @FXML
    public void listTypeOfTransactionClicked() {
        createTab("TypeOfTransaction", buildTypeOfTransactionTab());
    }

    @FXML
    public void listAccountClicked() {
        createTab("Compte", buildAccountTab());
    }

    @FXML
    public void listUserClicked() {
        createTab("Utilisateur", buildUserTab());
    }


}
```

Comment: Usualy I only create the exe and if is found within target under `jfx/native/{project-name}-${project-verions}`

Comment: how do you configure pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `jar` file as an output because you execute `jfx:jar` goal.

To get native packages you should call `jfx:native`. You'll find your packages under `target/jfx/native/`.

By the way, there's nice maven config generator (bit outdated version of plugin, but still works) [here](http://javafx-maven-plugin.github.io/). It not only allows you to generate working maven plugin configuration, but also explains all configuration properties and tells you what goal should you call.

Comment: After executing the  <goal>build-native</goal>, it generated an executable perfectly, but only the mainWindow that works. I'm still not be able to make other windows works, i think he don't included the resources file. Anyway, i have updated my post with the updated pom.xml file

Comment: @abdouamer please add also the code fragment where you instantiate new window. It's worth checking if these `fxml` files exist in your `jar` file (generated via `jfx:jar`)

Comment: Yes, when i open the JAR file i see the fxml folder where i put my fxml files.

Comment: If I understand you correctly - there are `fxml` files in generated `jar`. The problem is that application does not see them and throw exception. It all depends on the way you're trying to open resource (in your case `fxml` file) and where it is located. The code working with IDE can be useless in JAR file. Why is your path for getting other `fxml`s look different to the one for `mainWindow.fxml`? Let's try to make it: `getResource("fxml/user/user.fxml")` (note that I removed `../` part)

Comment: It not throw and exception, it just open new blank tab.

Comment: No, you can't delete "../" from path, because the mainWindowController is located on a src/main/controller package , so to be able to access the src/main/resources/fxml   file you have to do "../fxml/user.fxml".

Comment: @abdouamer I think that this discussion is slowly becoming a good topic for another SO question. My project structure looks like [this](http://imgur.com/rL1kpxg) and I am able to get any resource by simply getClass().getResource("/fxml/nameOfMyResource").

Comment: yes, sure it works, my problem was "/", i'm using fxml/ instead of /fxml/ , so thank's

Comment: The URL to the Maven Config generator is broken :(