# Deploying javafx hsqldb project with maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx, deployment, hsqldb

I did a lot of research and still couldnt manage to deploy it, to a single .jar file I mean.
Is it easy to do with maven? I don't know how to add hsqldb to maven and how to get jar from maven (I could only set jfx:run as goal) my maven POM for now is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>excellkan</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.openjfx.excellkan.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I would appreciate any help and advise. Thank you already.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with `Maven`, but to add the HSQLDB to it, do the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Got this from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb/2.5.0).

As for deploying it as a `.jar`, you need to "execute `jfx:jar` goal", which I saw being mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722625/javafx-maven-deployment-under-intellij-idea).

Comment: that goal doesnt work for my version of jfx archetype, and I couldn't find the older version

Comment: @BATIKANBORAORMANCI you can find older version of JavaFX here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx